# Cannot clone my own repository from github to my www folder

Tags: git, github, clone

I am using linux mint. I am new to git. I have pushed one repository from my local computer to github. Then I have reinstalled my os. Now I am trying to clone that repo and bring it back to my www folder. I can clone it in my home folder. But whenever I try to clone in my www folder then I get this error saying permission denied.

Here is my command

```
sudo git clone git@github.com:username/projectname.git /var/www/projectname/
```

I get this error

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Comment: did you add the root pubkey also to your github account? if not it will not work.. or why do you need sudo?

Comment: the error message says otherwise.

Comment: I need sudo because only root user has write permission inside /var/www folder

Comment: I have said it that I can clone it in my home folder

Comment: clone the repo in your home directory and `sudo mv repo /var/www/repo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an ssh url, which means you need to re-create your ssh keys and add the public one to your GitHub account.
See "[Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)".

If the clone doesn't work with `sudo`, it is because it will look for those keys in `~root/.ssh`, whereas they are in `~yourUser/.ssh`.
One quick workaround would at least to copy those keys:

```
sudo cp /home/yourUser/.ssh/id_* /root/.ssh/
```

A better solution would be to generate a different set of keys for root, and register the public root ssh key to your GitHub account.

Other solutions are discussed at "[How can I run SSH as a different user on the same Ubuntu installation?](https://askubuntu.com/q/267696)", including [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/267702):

Running a script as root, which will use the user environment for the git command:

```
su -lc "git clone git@github.com:username/projectname.git /var/www/projectname/" yourUser
```

That way, you don't need to duplicate keys or generate new ones.

Comment: I get the error only when I try to clone it in my /var/www/project folder

Comment: are saying to clone it in my home folder and then copy the folder to the www directory?

Comment: oh, i got it. wait for one moment, let me try that